# Simulate HTTP POST (Form)?

Tags: php, forms

I need to populate my database with test data. But my data needs to be manipulated to be put into the form by my PHP FORM before upload.

How can I automatic the process of filling out my web application form field, which also need to accept uploading images?

Comment: Why can't you add the data directly to your database using a DB management tool?

Answer (score 2):

Progamatically, you can do this by making a post request in your language of choice.

Tool wise, you can use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which has support for making HTTP Post requests.

You'll have to fill out the HTTP Request body properly; usually form post variables look like this:

`name1=value1&name2=value2`

Or use `curl`.

This [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl) question shows how to make an HTTP post using `curl`.